# Is it possible to save form data through with Vue.js through Controller without Axios or asynchronous call?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have a function in my controller that is used to store data. I am recreating my front end using Vue.js. As of now, I removed the current Laravel {{ Form: }} with Vue.js. Can I use same synchronous route without api to post the data? APIs are not ready and I cannot wait to validate my forms

Comment: you can still send post request to your original method, there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: You can use the same route, there are not asynchrnous routes in laravel. You tried and faced with a problem?

Comment: @AndySong is there documentation I can refer to or example? I couldn't find any

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, all you need to do is to be aware that HTML does not have methods other than GET and POST. So, if you have PUT, DELETE and others, you're going to have to use the _method param trick.So, for example, when using the PUT http verb, you should create your form something like this:

```
<form method='POST'>
       yourfields...
       <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
</form>
```

Other than that, it's pretty much calling the correct endpoints from your Vue application.

Comment: So what i did so far is added action and method to my v-form. How about CSRF token ?  <v-form v-model="valid" action="users/store" method="POST">
            <v-card-text>
                    <v-container>
                        <v-row>
                        <v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="6">
                            <v-text-field label="First Name:" v-model="firstName" enableSaveButton></v-text-field>
                        </v-col> ........